# How to practically apply Css to a wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

This is for learning sakes guys, i realized i spent time learning the theory of languages like css, html and soon php and java script but i am having difficulty in applying it. Example, if i am using a page builder plugin, can i edit the css of elements normally(it is usually encoded differently)? When editing css, should i use the editor from wordpress or a css plugin? How to use the custom css of plugins, do i give it class and id, provide the path and edit the css? i welcome all knowledge in customizing the css and html of pages, posts,  etc.

I will appreciate all advice and tips.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

It's good practice to change the CSS only inside your WP theme (child-theme).
No matter where the element is generated for the page, you can stylize them all from your style.css.

For example, on the page you have some elements created in different places:

```
<div class="this_div_generated_by_page_builder_plugin">Text</div>
<div class="this_div_generated_by_another_plugin">Text</div>
<div class="this_div_generated_no_matter_where">Text</div>
```

You can stylize it all from your /wp-content/themes/your_theme/style.css via something like this:

```
.this_div_generated_by_page_builder_plugin {
   color: black;
}
.this_div_generated_by_another_plugin {
   color: white;
}
.this_div_generated_no_matter_where {
   color: gray;
}
```